# How to generate a firebase download token

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage

How do we go about generating a [firebase download token](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iaYph.png) within the admin SDK, knowing it can easily be done with the client SDK.

I understand the client SDK acts as a wrapper on the storage SDK, therefore it adds this functionality, but then, why not giving the admin SDK the same option. I just want to know how to generate that token myself, with the current SDK, because I need the URLs to have the same format as the ones generated within the client, and using `getSignedURL`, the format is way different and does not abide to the firebase storage rules, nor it is permanent, as it expires after a set amount of time.

Comment: If you're looking to file a feature request, Stack Overflow is not the place for that. Please [file a feature request](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/) with Firebase's support team.

Comment: I've already done that. I'm still wondering how do we go about doing that with the current API, given I actually need this in production. What happens is that a file on upload, is sent towards a 3rd party service, encoded, uploaded back to the cloud storage, then we need to generate a new download URL obviously. So, given `object.refFromURL()` does not work in that case, we're stuck with an app that crashes on urls generated via signedURL. If it can be done via the client SDK, we can surely do it from the admin SDK. That's without doubt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to get an URL exactly like the one `getDownloadURL` from the `client SDK`, while using the `admin SDK`, all you need to do is to update the object's `metadata` with a key called `firebaseStorageDownloadTokens`. Contrary to what everyone else says, you don't need that `signedUrl`.

> $uuid = someUuidMethod();
>
> $object->update([ 'metadata' => [ 'firebaseStorageDownloadTokens' => $uuid ] ]);

2. The moment you run the above, you'll get an error as follows:

> serviceaccount does not have storage.objects.update access

In which case, you need to go to the `IAM` section in `GCP Console`, select your service account ( the one mentioned in the error ), `Edit roles`, and add another role `Storage > Owner`.

3. Run the `update` command again, and job is done. You can now generate your own tokens. It's needed when you rely on cloud services to work on your storage files.

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you're mistaken on one point.  The download URLs created by the Storage SDKs on the client do not actually "abide by security rules".  Anyone who has that download URL can read the object.  This is no different than signed URLs generated by the server SDKs.

Both types of URL are functionally equivalent. The obvious exception is that signed URLs have an expiration, but you can set that expiration arbitrarily far in the future that it makes no difference.

To put it in short - client download URLs can't be generated by the server SDKs, and signed URLs can't be generated by the client SDK, but it doesn't matter because they serve the same purpose.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I just realised the rules within firebase storage are for people who want access to the actual "objects" in the bucket, not for the public to read / write. So, on topic, what if I create those uuid tokens myself, and update the file's metadata directly. Would that "work" ? (trying right now)

Comment: Sorry, I don't know.

Comment: Yep. I just updated the metadata token to another uuid v4, and worked just fine. Only issue now is that the service credentials generated within firebase do not seem to have enough permissions to update objects metadata. Trying to figure that out now, and will post a new answer.